# how to change the parsley error message style?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple form validation using parsley, but I don't like the error message that appears.  It's like an pop up that says "Please fill out this field".  How can I change to be like this?

Full Name: [assuming text files]
*Please input your full name! (this would be the error message and I would style it if possible.)

Is it possible to have that error messsage below the text field? And auto validating the field while inserting to the field? It's validating the input field while not clicking the submit button.

Thanks guys in advance! .:-)

Answer (score 1):

try to style parsley-required class 
something like

```
.parsley-required{
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**Parsley** is a really powerful tool. If you want to change the error message you could try using something like this:

```
data-parsley-error-message="Enter your message here"
```

I also like to include a css file just for parsley that style's the elements based on the classes that parsley generates. I use inspector to find those.

Comment: Please note the original question was about changing the `style` of the parsley message, not the `contents`.

Comment: It's not all about style. If you read the first paragraph he's asking how to change the contents and then added that he'd like to style.

Comment: answer seem to be off question